# Locating a template file in an ansible module

Tags: python, ansible

I'm writing a small python module for ansible. I'm passing a filename in one of its parameters and I'd like to 'locate' this file in the same manner as the src parameter for the template module does.

Example:

```
- name: Standard template usage
  template:
    src: source.dat.j2
    dest: /home/user/target.dat

- name: My task using my own module
  mynewmodule:
     src: source.dat
     dest: /home/user/target.dat
```

Here I'd like to locate the file source.dat in the same manner as it would happen with source.dat.j2.
Is there an ansible fuction/method/module I can reuse in my module or do I have to implement my own lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the answer is a bit deeper than you expect.

To work with local files, you have to write an action plugin for your module to do all preparation job on control host before executing module on remote host. There's a tiny note about it in [the docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules.html):

> For modules like file/copy/template, some of the work needs to be done on the master before the module executes on the target. Action plugins execute first on the master and can then execute the normal module on the target if necessary.

And there's a helper method [_find_needle](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/9dc41ae578a53fe906ef685e322e8cbbd07a04f3/lib/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py#L970) of `ActionBase` class to search files in expected paths (roles, includes, etc).

You can see example usage inside [template](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/9dc41ae578a53fe906ef685e322e8cbbd07a04f3/lib/ansible/plugins/action/template.py#L72) action plugin.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the action plugin! That probably would have cost me quite some time ...

Comment: Is there an official documentation for this function?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to use `_find_needle` from [lib/ansible/plugins/action/**init**.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py#L972).

```
def _find_needle(self, dirname, needle):

'''
find a needle in haystack of paths, optionally using 'dirname' as a subdir.
This will build the ordered list of paths to search and pass them to dwim
to get back the first existing file found.
'''
```